# Ladda button spin animation not showing on input elements

Tags: jquery, plugins

Using [Ladda](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) plugin for buttons with built-in loading indicators. I've been able to get it working on button and href elements, but not on a input. More specifically, the spin animation. It doesn't show. Everything works, but it just doesn't show the spin.

**CODE:**

```
<input class="ladda-button" type="submit" data-color="green" data-style="expand-left">
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you guys!

Comment: The reason is that `input` element is an `inline element` - it can not have children, so markup becomes invalid and children `span` tag are not  accessed by `css`.

Comment: @Dharmang That makes sense. Pity as that means I cannot use the library. See my comment to AntPhitlok below.

Comment: I see, I would suggest to grab input tags by some means in `document ready` event by `jQuery` and replace it with `button` tag, then apply `Ladda` plugin call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace your `<input type="submit>` with `<button type="submit"></button>`.

```
<button type="submit" class="ladda-button" data-style="expand-left">Hello</button>
```

Modern web browsers will treat this functionally the same as an `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Unfortunately the html is being generated (by ASP.NET) and I have no control over changing the tags from an <input> to a <button>

Comment: How about using <button type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick=""></button>?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to grab input tags by some means in `document ready` event by `jQuery` and replace it with `button` tag, then apply `Ladda` plugin call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net you can use asp:LinkButton instead of asp:Button. This will render an anchor element and Ladda will work just fine.